# 2006 AWD Honda CRV Engine shutter/limp mode at 3000 RPM (replaced VTECH Solenoid)

Tags: crv

HI and thanks for the help.

I have a 2006 Honda CRV AWD runs fine ,,Until engine hit speeds of over 45 MPH or RPM's exceed 3000
Once this happens the Check engine light & VSA & Warning light and the engine enters Limp Mode.
The code was for a VTECH Solenoid that we replaced but the problem persists.
The car does not burn oil, power and function at lower speeds/rpms  is excellent, car is not smoking. CRV has 205 K miles.

Mechanic has suggested a new Oil Pump ($1000.00 installed) using Honda Factory Part.

Please help!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the exact code which comes up?

Comment: 2646................

Comment: What type of oil is being used? According to what I just read, you should be using 5W-20 full synthetic. If you are using something like 5W-30 or 10W-30, this could be fouling the VTEC system. If you have been utilizing conventional oil instead of fully synthetic, this could be causing sludge or buildup in the oil passages, which could also be fouling the VTEC. The code you have is for the rocker arm actuator. I'm not sure if that's the same thing as the VTEC Solenoid you had replaced.